# Regroup an IGrouping by original group criteria

Tags: c#, linq

This sounds stupid (maybe the answer is quite easy), but I just don't see a solution for this issue:

Let's say I have this:

```
public IGrouping<T, Item> process<T>(IGrouping<T,Item> group)
{
       var toIgnore = group.AsEnumerable().Where(ignoreExpression);
       var toContinue = group.AsEnumerable().Except(toIgnore);      

       // how to group the "toContinue" Enumerable by the same criteria as the group ?
       //

       return newGroup;
 }
```

What I want to do is: I get the group, I want to ignore some items in each group (not whole groups). So far so good. Then I want to re-group it, according to the original criteria - and that's where I'm stuck.

How could this be done? I can find the original criteria from the grouping (this is group.Key of course), but how can I re-group the result "toContinue" (or even toContinue.ToList()) by group.Key?

thx for suggestions

Andreas

Comment: Why don't you filter the items before grouping it?

Comment: this "process" method is part of a work queue - I just want to filter out some items in the group and return the result. There are other processors in the queue expecting the same type of elements (grouped by the same key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group key is on IGrouping Key property.

Since IGrouping is IEnumerable once you make a Where, you loose the grouping key. You have to filter before the GroupBy(), not after

Comment: That's all clear. The question is: How can I group a list (let's say a new list of the same Item type) according to the original Key?

Comment: Since you are dealing with T, and not a specific type, you can't.  That's why I think you should better do the filtering before the process method. Or return IEnumerable<T> instead of IGrouping<T, Item>.

Comment: I agree -> as I am not doing the grouping my self, I just return the IEnumerable<T>. Then the queue processor need to group it again (he knows the type, he can do it).